# Position not changed by animation

Tags: javascript, svg.js

This question is about SVG.js

I use two `move` commands on animations of two SVG objects to swap their positions. I then use a callback from `afterAll` to move one of these objects further. I find that I need to specify my new position relative the the previous changes, i.e. from the position of the object right at the start. This is a headache, for keeping track of old coordinate changes (deltas).

So:

- do I need to "commit" (or finish) my animation to change the object position permanently, before moving on? How?
- am I accidentally re-using the FX object by calling `animation()` again on the same object at a different part in the code?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Some code in JSFiddle (for example) may help us understand what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ksp6zg4w/
I cut out most of the code for clarity

Comment: Can you provide placeholder objects as well? Also, you should update your original post with the code (link and/or in-post), instead of putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to swap SVG images maybe you don't need a library (A and B options)

A) To do so you can rely on basic CSS transition.

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#one {
  background-color: #39464e; 
  left: 0;
}

#two {
  background-color: #ff4f68;
  right: 0;
}

body.swap #one {
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
  transition: 5s;
}

body.swap #two {
  right: calc(100% - 100px);
  transition: 5s;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gengns/et9dbpur/

You can use a svg tag instead of a div or set your SVG in a div background-image.

B) If you don't want to animate, just simple swap them you can do it in a declarative way with CSS Grid.

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'one two';
}

body.swap {
  grid-template-areas: 'two one';
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#one {
  background-color: #39464e; 
  grid-area: one;
}

#two {
  background-color: #ff4f68;
  grid-area: two;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gengns/bsacypd8/

C) Using svg.js 2.7.1

```
SVG.on(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const draw = SVG('drawing')

  // Rectangles
  const rect_one = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: '#39464e'})
  const rect_two = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: '#ff4f68'}).move(500, 0)

  // Swap
  rect_one.animate().move(500, 0)
  rect_two.animate().move(0, 0).after(() => {
    // Swap again
    rect_one.animate().move(0, 0)
    rect_two.animate().move(500, 0)
  })
})
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gengns/497j1z0a/

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks for the code! The reason I was doing it in JS was that I want to do this programmatically, individually over and over again.

The full story is that I'm visually filling a tree structure with nodes many times over... that would be a bit weird in CSS?

Comment: If I understood you well, you can use option C and set as many rect/nodes as you like.

Comment: Well, that (C) is sort of what I have. But the coordinates are not updated, i.e. I have to keep track of all applied deltas myself.

Comment: I played a bit with the (C) fiddle, it does seem to work... I must work with my own code some more to see what to do...

Comment: One problem seems to be that I am working with groups (containing a circle and some text). But groups don't have x / y position according to the docs? So what exactly is moved when I animate them?

Comment: Ok, solved it using `nested`s instead of `group`s, that made the difference. Thanks again!